# Where is my 25 reputation?

Tags: riddle, cipher, story

You, Detective Ryan, are packing up, as you are retiring. You have to say goodbye to your best friend, Wudriwurds. You open his last letter that he gave you, and read it with all your heart.

> Dear Ryan,
>
> It is very hard for me to say farewell, as we have worked together to solve many mysteries. I want to make this last message to you as special as possible, so I have one last puzzle for you to solve. It should lead you to a special place, one that has a lot of meaning to both of us, where you will find many up votes to use. But the journey to this place will be challenging. It will not just be an easy puzzle or cipher. Once you go to the place your first clue will lead you to, you will find 25 rep, as well as a clue to lead you on to the next place, and so forth. Here is your first clue: 112 111 101 109 46 104 111 110 101 115 116 46 114 111 98 111 116. I wish you good luck!
>
> Farewell,
>           Wudriwurds

Another puzzle? Looks like your detectiveness is not coming to an end yet after all. You are eager to receive your reputation. Where should you go first?

Hint 1:

> Both names have meaning

Comment: Is he Wudriwurds or Wadriwurds? Is it just a typo? Or a typo being a part of the puzzle?

Comment: What about the _too_ at the end of _'the place your first clue will lead you too'_...?

Comment: Wudriwurds is not a typo, too is.

Comment: As I can see now, Wadriwurds was a typo, too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Following on from @joe-you-know's partial answer:

> Wudriwurds references the online geocoding system 'what three words' - in this system, poem.honest.robot yields the location of A Block in Alcatraz Prison. (https://map.what3words.com/poem.honest.robot).

Comment: You go to Alcatraz, and you find 25 reputation from Wudriwurds, and a lot from other people to. Near the cell, you find your next clue...

Answer (score 7):

Partial Answer:
In other words, what I've figured out so far,

> The decimal, when converted to text, spells out poem.honest.robot
>  I'm still trying to figure out what it means

Answer (score 3):

Working on clue 2.

I've been trying to look at nearby 3 word locations and plugging them in to what3words.

golden.gate.bridge and fisher.man.wharf and variations on those (e.g. gate.golden.bridge) yielded nothing, but point.blunt.rock just north of alcatraz does give a spot in Bardstown, Kentucky... [https://w3w.co/point.blunt.rock]

Doubt this is correct, but maybe uses the right methodology?

Comment: I didn't write clue 2 yet...

Comment: Wait, so this puzzle will be in parts?

Comment: Ah ok. Your commend under the answer to the first clue was somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: yes, it will be in parts